# Can Playwright be used along with Azure libraries?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, playwright, e2e

I'm new to .NET Playwright and I read a little about its back-end testing capabilities. I would like to know if I can use Playwright functionality along with Azure libraries like `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`? Can I join them?

This is a part of a code which sends a batch of messages into a Service Bus queue:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfMessages; i++)
{
    // try adding a message to the batch
    if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage($"Message {i}")))
    {
        // if it is too large for the batch
        throw new Exception($"The message {i} is too large to fit in the batch.");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do the same with Playwright but without reinventing the wheel? It would be perfect if it would be possible to work on E2E Azure Service Bus automation tests with the use of already existing Azure libraries.

Comment: Not sure that I follow what you're trying to do.  Playwright is a test framework for browser-based user interfaces.   Service Bus is a backend service with no UI.   Can you help us understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Mateuszpodsiadlo Hope this reference [helps](https://www.mrjamiebowman.com/software-development/dotnet/net-unit-testing-azure-service-bus/)

Comment: @MateuszPodsiadło ran a  test case in the c# console app with`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`

Comment: @MateuszPodsiadło refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2)

Answer (score 0):

- Using this [reference](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro), I am able to send messages to an Azure Service Bus queue using Playwright for UI automation.
- The `SendMessagesToAzureServiceBusQueue` method simulates sending messages to an Azure Service Bus queue. Using the connection string, queue name, and number of messages specified in the `numOfMessages` variable and the process of sending messages to an Azure Service Bus queue is an example of E2E testing in Azure Service Bus applications.

```cs
   [TestFixture]
   public class Tests
   {
       private IConfiguration _configuration;
       private ILogger<Tests> _logger;

       [SetUp]
       public void SetUp()
       {
           // Load Azure Service Bus connection string from appsettings.json
           _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();

           // Configure logging
           var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
           {
               builder.AddConsole();
           });
           _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Tests>();
       }

       [Test]
       public async Task SendMessagesToServiceBus()
       {
           using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
           var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();

           try
           {
               // Redirect console output to a custom TextWriter
               Console.SetOut(new CustomTextWriter());

               // Create a Playwright page
               var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
               var page = await context.NewPageAsync();

               page.GotoAsync("https://");

               // Check if the "send-button" is present
               var sendButton = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#send-button");

               if (sendButton != null)
               {
                   // If the button is present, simulate clicking it
                   await sendButton.ClickAsync();

                   // Send a batch of messages to Azure Service Bus
                   string connectionString = _configuration["ServiceBusConnectionString"];
                   string queueName = "buffer-notifications"; // Replace with your queue name
                   int numOfMessages = 10; // Replace with the desired number of messages

                   await SendToServiceBus(connectionString, queueName, numOfMessages);
               }
               else
               {
                   _logger.LogInformation("The 'send-button' element is not present on the page.");
                   // Handle the absence of the button as needed
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               _logger.LogError($"Error in Playwright test: {ex.Message}");
           }
           finally
           {
               // Close the browser
               await browser.CloseAsync();
           }
       }

       [Test]
       public async Task SendMessagesToAzureServiceBusQueue()
       {
           // Replace with your Azure Service Bus connection string and queue name
           string connectionString = "Your-Service-Bus-Connection-String";
           string queueName = "Your-Queue-Name";
           int numOfMessages = 5; // Specify the number of test messages to send

           try
           {
               await SendToServiceBus(connectionString, queueName, numOfMessages);
               _logger.LogInformation($"Successfully sent {numOfMessages} messages to the queue '{queueName}'");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               _logger.LogError($"Error sending messages to Azure Service Bus: {ex.Message}");
               Assert.Fail($"Failed to send messages to Azure Service Bus: {ex.Message}");
           }
       }

       private async Task SendToServiceBus(string connectionString, string queueName, int numOfMessages)
       {
           await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
           var sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

           for (int i = 1; i <= numOfMessages; i++)
           {
               var message = new ServiceBusMessage($"Message {i}");
               await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
               _logger.LogInformation($"Message sent to {queueName}: {message.Body}");
           }

           await sender.CloseAsync();
       }
   }

   class CustomTextWriter : TextWriter
   {
       private readonly TextWriter _originalWriter;
       private readonly FileStream _outputFileStream;

       public CustomTextWriter()
       {
           _originalWriter = Console.Out;

           // Redirect console output to a file
           _outputFileStream = new FileStream("test_output.txt", FileMode.Create);
           Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(_outputFileStream));
       }

       public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;

       public override void Write(char value)
       {
           _originalWriter.Write(value); // Optionally log to the original console
           _outputFileStream.WriteByte((byte)value);
       }

       public override void Write(string value)
       {
           _originalWriter.Write(value); // Optionally log to the original console
           byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
           _outputFileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       }
   }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]